# asynchronous execution of a macro row by row

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I am trying to fix a problem that I am having with Bloomberg add-in for Excel. Each day I populate 31 days of historical price data for 500+ stocks.

$A$K3 = "ACE US EQUITY" $AL$3 = "=BDH(AK3,"PX_LAST",$D$1,$C$1,"DTS=h","dir=h")" $C$1 = "=WORKDAY(TODAY(),0)" $D$1 = "=BAddPeriods(C1,"NumberOfPeriods=-31","Per=wd","CDR=#A")"

What is supposed to happen is that in $AL$3:$BQ$3 there will be prices for 31 days.

I leave the workbook open as the Bloomberg DDE session remains open for 3 days even if the Bloomberg executable is not running.

Sometimes there is no problem and when I come into work the following day, the data is shifted forward by one day. Other times, much of the data is missing and I am forced to select and refresh each $AL$_ field. The problem with this is that for some reason the refresh is happening synchronously and I think this is causing havoc on the DDE connection and/or Excel. Resulting in slow/no updates. Also, if I refresh the entire worksheet some formulas will be overwritten with static data!

What I would like to do is create a macro that will:

> 1) clear all data in $AL$*:$BQ*$ & $BS$*:$CX*$
>
> 2) set the value of $AL$_ =
>   "=BDH(AK$_,"PX_LAST",$D$1,$C$1,"DTS=h","dir=h")"
>
> 3) wait until the data is populated into $AL$*:$BQ$* before going to
>   $AL$(+1):$BQ$(+1); if $AM$_ has a value then most likely the data has
>   populated in that row.
>
> 4) then when $AL$*:$BQ$* is finished, do the same for $BS$*:$CX$*

I have been waiting for Bloomberg support to fulfill this request for over one month now with no results.

I don't have enough experience to get this going.

I have a very minute amount of code below which I created using the recorder:

```
Sub PopulateData()
'
' PopulateData Macro 
'

'
Range("AL2:BQ2").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("AL2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=BDH(RC[-1],""PX_LAST"",R1C4,R1C3,""DTS=h"",""dir=h"")"
Range("AL2").Select
End Sub
```

While I selected the refresh button while recording, this action was not recorded.
Thank you for looking.

Comment: The DDE api is sometimes fragile. Wouldn't it be simpler to use the vba api and manually fetch the data? You could combine that with a scheduled task that runs every day at 6am for example.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean.  Programming 'talk' is sometimes foreign to me since I am a novice here...

Comment: I have determined that it is expressly related to having Calculations set to Automatic.  Now I will need to figure out how to get calculations to run while having the spreadsheet set to Manual.

Answer (score 0):

A macro solution that would run the formula one line at a time, then overwrite the formulas with the values so simultaneous queries are not performed on the next iteration:

```
Sub CalculateLineByLine
   For Each c In Range("AL2:AL501")
      c.FormulaR1C1 = "=BDH(RC[-1],""PX_LAST"",R1C4,R1C3,""DTS=h"",""dir=h"")"
      Calculate
      Range(c.address, "BQ" & c.row)).Copy
      c.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   Next c
End Sub
```

I didn't manually clear the contents because I assumed the old data would just be overwritten with paste special. I hope this will work as a possible solution for you.

If I read your last comment correctly, you were looking to press F9 to manually calculate all open workbooks when formulas are set to manual.